# How to manage ZF2 modules the right way

Tags: github, zend-framework2, composer-php, dependency-management, git-submodules

I am new to ZF2. I have decided to download ZendSkeletonApplication to ease start of development. I will be developing my own modules for my application. I will also be using various vendor modules.

So I did `git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git`

Then I did `php composer.phar self-update` and `php composer.phar update`
I am off to a good start, yes?

**Question:**

I am using git. I have noticed that despite me using composer.phar, when I've added some dependencies using composer, I still managed to somehow acquire git submodules.  And when I push those to GitHub, only the `pointers` to those submodules are being pushed, and not the files.  Because I am making changes in the submodules to make them custom to my application, I kind of need to manage both composer and git submodules to ensure my changes are pushed to GitHub.  Do I just go on doing this, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the directory named `vendor` into the `.gitignore` file and not commit anything inside to your repository. Do avoid the git submodules - Composer will take care of all dependencies.

What you should commit however is the `composer.json` and the created `composer.lock` file. If you check out your repository later in a different location, you have to run `composer install` to completely recreate the installed dependencies. They are exactly specified in that composer.lock file.